# Query builder Codeignitier Join

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

Buenos días estoy intentando realizar un Join con el query builder de Codeignitier, comparando un valor que traigo desde una variable que nombro id, 
la función que estoy usando es la siguiente:

```
function detalle($id = NULL){

        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('usuarios');
        $this->db->join('ficha', 'usuarios'.$id = 'ficha'.$id);
        $this->db->limit(1);
        return $query = $this->db->get()->result_array();

    }
```

pero me arroja el siguiente error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function detalle($id = NULL){
   $this->db->select('*');
   $this->db->from('usuarios');
   $this->db->join('ficha', 'usuarios.id = ficha.id');
   $this->db->where('usuarios.id',$id);
   return $this->db->get()->row_array();
}
```

En primer lugar, haces el join entre los registros en los que coincidan el id de usuario y el id de la ficha (no hace falta especificar un valor concreto).

En segundo lugar (Para espoecificar el valor concreto) aplicas un where pasando el usuarios.id o puedes pasar el ficha.id, cualquiera de los dos te valdría (porque se supone que el join anterior ha unido los que tienen el mismo id usuario e id de ficha).

Después, en vez de poner un limit de 1 y devolver un result_array(), con poner directamente row_array() te devuelve 1 registro.

por otro lado, esto es raro:

```
return $query = $this->db->get()->result_array()
```

Esto te va a devolver TRUE si se han generado resultados y false si no se han generado, pero en ningún caso te va a devolver los resultados en sí.

Comment: muchas gracias le hice un par de modificaciones, y al final lo regrese con el limit de 1 y como array así se me hacia mas fácil recorrer el arreglo con un foreach, gracias.